# Need a scalable way to Limit Content by using substr() and strpos() in PHP

Tags: php, string, markdown, substr, strpos

I am using **Markdown** to render a rich content on a page, using PHP. For the brief version, I think it would be fine to truncate the content till second paragraph, or technically, after two `\r\n` have crossed. So I used this code:

```
substr($content, 0, strpos($content, "\r\n\r\n", strpos($content, "\r\n\r\n") + 1));
```

Since the count of `\r\n` is hard coded, and is also calculated in a weird way, *(using +1 after the first position and stuff)*, is there a better way I can make a function, which says `limitContent($content, $lines = 2)` and passing the number of lines to the `$lines` parameter, as by default, it truncates to two lines?

My current code is:

```
/**
 * Break down the content of Markdown upto 2 breaks. 
 * @param string Markdown String
 * @return string Markdown String upto 2 breaks
 */
function limitContent($content)
{
    return substr($content, 0, strpos($content, "\r\n\r\n", strpos($content, "\r\n\r\n") + 1));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, both Nin and Jack have answered my question and both are good. Cannot select both the answers as Best Answer! :P Now help me choose one! :)

Comment: We can't help you with that decision :)

Comment: Hey Jack, I was able to use the code by Nin, so selecting his answer as best. But have given both of you an upvote. This is what best I was able to do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I misunderstood. Is this what you want?

```
function limitContent($content, $lines=2)
{
    $tmp=explode("\r\n\r\n", $content);
    $tmp=array_slice($tmp,0,$lines);
    return implode("\r\n", $tmp);
}
```

[edit]
And slightly better would be:

```
function limitContent($content, $lines=2)
    {
        $tmp=explode("\r\n\r\n", $content, $lines+1);
        unset($tmp[$lines]);
        return implode("\r\n", $tmp);
    }
```

Comment: You got my question wrong. The content cannot be changed. I am trying to fetch content till I encounter nth `\r\n`.

Comment: Will this work as a single line script this way: `return implode("\r\n", array_slice(explode("\r\n\r\n", $content), 0, $lines));`

Comment: yes, you could do it in one line and yes that should be \r\n\r\n

Comment: In the code, which I said above in one line, should it be `$lines` or `$lines + 1`?

Comment: just lines, but you can try it out and see what the outcome is ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `explode()` for that:

```
join("\r\n", array_slice(explode("\r\n\r\n", $content, $lines + 1), 0, $lines));
```

Or similarly, using `preg_split()` - to match both LF and CRLF:

```
join("\r\n", array_slice(preg_split("/(?:\r?\n){2}/", $content, $lines), 0, $lines));
```

Above solutions are not very memory efficient though, because the full content after the last match is copied into the last array element.

You could also use `strtok()` as this might be more memory efficient:

```
$result = '';
for ($i = 0, $tok = strtok($s, "\r\n\r\n"); false !== $tok && $i < $lines; ++$i, $tok = strtok("\r\n\r\n")) {
        $result .= $t . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: the post by Nin is better. But let me know which will be consuming less memory?

Comment: @PraveenKumar How is his/her answer better? I see almost the same code.

Comment: @Jack, only difference is that you need to ditch the last item from the array. Preg_split should not be used if you can don't really need regexp. Which, in this case you don't.

Comment: @Nin but `explode()` with a limit of 2 would give at most 2 paragraphs, which should be the same as OP's `substr()` solution ...

Comment: @nin the `preg_split()` solution has the advantage of matching both LF and CRLF, whereas `explode()` only takes a fixed string.

Comment: @Jack:  `If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.` So the last element will contain everything. So you need to limit by $lines+1 and remove the last one.

Comment: @Jack, if you need that flexibility, you could use preg_split. However, if you don't need it, stay away from using regexp.

Comment: @Nin I believe in giving options :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar please check my updated answer; added one more option I thought of.

Comment: Hey guys, no fighting. I just didn't prefer `preg_*` functions. The code given by Nin was very simple and precise. Lemme just consider the memory limitation and usage for firing this on 2500 MarkDown functions... :)

Answer (score 1):

I was interessted in the performance difference between both options in [Nin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172659/need-a-scalable-way-to-limit-content-by-using-substr-and-strpos-in-php/12173905#12173905) so I started a quick check with some data I had at hand. I tested against 2 string: a long string with many paragraphs and one long string with 2 paragraphs.

`Option 2` turn out to be `14 times faster` on the first string and `6% faster` on the second string. So this has a huge advantage on the first string.

Moreover I turned [Praveen Kumar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172659/need-a-scalable-way-to-limit-content-by-using-substr-and-strpos-in-php) initial idea into a simple loop based version and tested it:

```
function limitContent($content, $lines=2) {
    $pos = -1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $lines; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($content, "\r\n\r\n", $pos+1);
        if ($pos === false) return $content;
    }
    return substr($content, 0, $pos);
}
```

This version turned out to be another `178 times faster` on the first string and another `25 times faster` on the second string. While these numbers might change a lot for you depending on data and php version I think it clearly shows that converting to an array and back is slow. I'd probably still use  Nin's idea if performance is not a concern because it's pretty straight forward to read.

Comment: Wow... That's a huge amount of tests you have done boss.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I would have made it a comment but it was a bit long. But hey commenting on help with sarcasm ... that's the way to go dude !